# Exception handling mechanism on Solaris

Tags: c++, exception, solaris

I'm building an error handling mechanism for a C++ application. Right now, I got the windows part done using VectoredExceptionHandling and I wanted to know if there is a similar concept on Solaris. Basically, whenever an exception is thrown from anywhere in the program, I want to have a callback called. Under windows, you can register a callback using  `AddVectoredExceptionHandler()`. How do I do this for Solaris?

Comment: Such things mostly depending on the compiler you use

Comment: I'm wondering whether you're mixing Windows native Structured Exception Handling (SEH) and C++ exceptions? `VectoredExceptionHandling` is for SEH, not C++ exceptions. Solaris doesn't have SEH exceptions.

Comment: @MSalters: are not C++ exceptions implemented on top of SEH on Windows? http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx

Comment: @Maxim: MSVC++ exceptions are in Win32, not sure about Intel C++ or MSVC++ on Win64.

Comment: I actually don't know, I'm registering the callback as stated and it gets called when an exception is thrown (via throw "..";).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% if this will work, but you can try to mimic the way gdb's catchpoints work: see http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_31.html The key piece of info is this:

"To stop just before an exception handler is called, you need some knowledge of the implementation. In the case of GNU C++, exceptions are raised by calling a library function named __raise_exception which has the following ANSI C interface:

```
/* addr is where the exception identifier is stored.
   id is the exception identifier.  */
void __raise_exception (void **addr, void *id);
```

To make the debugger catch all exceptions before any stack unwinding takes place, set a breakpoint on __raise_exception"

So, my guess is that you could install your own __raise_exception via LD_PRELOAD trick, for example.

Comment: ;-) thank you. Quite honestly, I'd be very impressed  to see a more "proper" solution in the UNIX world - its just such a weird functionality ... I mean, people write their exception handlers so they can handle exceptional conditions, right ? So, unless you're a debugger why would you want to install something on top of that ? But, MS people have their ideas, I'm sure they thought about this point when they offered this "vectored exception handling".